# What is this format? Binary? Hex?

Tags: binary, format, hex

I stumbled across the following data format.

```
\u6444\u50CF\u5934\u524D
```

Its not hexadecimal, its not binary, and I don't know what to call it. What IS it?

Comment: Why do you say it isn't hex?

Comment: Those are unicode characters.

Comment: The `\u` actually means that it's Unicode.  Referred to as the "Unicode escape".

Comment: Looks like 摄像头前 in Unicode characters. Google translates it like this http://goo.gl/d2RQVj

Comment: This is actually a useful question, can you think of a better title that will be more helpful to users searching with this question?

Comment: Also, Google gives the correct information if you search for `\u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are Unicode code points, which are encoded as 4 hex characters, for a total of 16 bits.

Comment: @TrippKinetics, Oops, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

looking at `\u50CF`..  part `50CF` tells it's `HEX` and `\u` tell it's `unicode` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was really confused.

Answer (score 0):

yup unicode,or, possibly utf-8 if coherent with it as established by the first two posts.

usually if it cannot be seen in an ascii chart you can tell it's neither hex,decimal,binary,or ascii.

therefore its either unicode, unicode big endian, utf, or utf-8
and in some cases these are interchangeable but only if they dont protain specifically to themselves
e.g.

INTERCHANGEABLE
UTF-8
HI ME

UNICODE
HI ME

NOT INTERCHANGEABLE
UNICODE
&&!@#$%^&*()

UTF-8
(SOMETHING ELSE)